# Windows.Forms.MessageBox In Page .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

First sorry for the english. I've recently found out that the MessageBox from Windows.Forms can be used in a web page, but there's a problem when showing it, it's not modal. Is there a way to make it modal?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are mistaken.  You can use the windows forms message box class from asp.net code and it won't cause an exception, but it won't ever show the message box in the page on the user's web browser.  Instead it shows the messagebox on a private desktop *on the server*.

There are third-party work-arounds you can find on the web that will help you build a modal message in an asp.net page, if you want (many of them rely on javascript's `confirm()` and `alert()` functions).